# open a local file in an android phone

Tags: android, cordova

How do you execute or open a file (e.g. a pdf file) in an android phone. I got the fileTransfer working, downloading a pdf file, but at a lost when trying to open the file. If that can't be done at least a way to put a notification that the download is completed in the notification bar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit following links for same.

http://code.google.com/p/apv/downloads/list

https://market.android.com/details?id=cx.hell.android.pdfview&feature=search_result

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/location/of/the/pdf.file")));
startActivity(intent);
```